# How do I pass the signal to the frequency domain?

Tags: matlab, filter, signals, signal-processing, fft

I have one noisy signal, and this signal is in the time domain. I want to draw this signal through the Fourier transform. As a result, what I expect is a Gaussian dispersion around 0. However, I don't know how to apply and draw the Fourier transform on my signal. I would be glad if you could help.

```
signalplusnoise=1x674
signalplusnoise=[0.0161,0.0308, 0.0112, ..., 0.3827]
```

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using matlab

Comment: Have you tried `fft(signalplusnoise)`?

Comment: Yes ı tried. a=fft(signalplusnoise); plot(a); but the graphic looks very different

Comment: You might want to plot the magnitude: `plot(abs(a))`, since the DFT is a complex-valued function. Note also that the DFT has frequencies k=0...N-1 on the horizontal axis. Nyquist frequency is at N/2, and the whole thing is periodic, meaning that the second half of the frequency components will be equal to the negative frequencies (k=-1 and k=N-1 are the same, etc.).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I did not fully understand what you said. I apologize for being a newbie. I don't have any data about frequency. I wonder what you call k and N

Comment: N is the number of samples, k is the frequencies. So if you start with a discrete signal x[n], with n=0..N-1, then applying the DFT (with the `fft` function) gives you a frequency-domain signal X[k], with k=0..N-1. You should read up about the DFT if you plan on using it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform